# Find a fixed commutative ring $R_0$ with 1, such that for every commutative ring $R$ with 1 $Hom(R_0)\to $ invertible elements of $R$ is bijection.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have some category theoretical problem I have reduced it to above problem. I cannot use initial object which is $\mathbb Z$ since morphisms would be unique but the invertible elements in the field would be infinite.

Any hint answer would be appreciated.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, take $R_0 = \mathbb Z[x,x^{-1}]$.

Comment: for example if $r\in R$ is unit how is the canonical morphism there

Comment: An element of $\mathbb Z[x,x^{-1}]$ is a formal sum of the form $\sum_{n \in \mathbb Z} a_nx^n$ where $a_n \neq 0$ for only finitely many $n \in \mathbb Z$. The canonical morphism is then evaluation-at-$r$.

Comment: Okay but I really cant understand the intuition behind it. If $r$ is not an unit of R why $\mathbb Z[x,x^{-1}]\to R$ is not ring homomorphism

Comment: If $r$ is not a unit, evaluation-at-$r$ doesn't not even makes sense. Note that in $\sum_{n \in \mathbb Z} a_nx^n$ we have **negative** powers.