# Canonical ring homomorphisms from $\mathbb Z[x,x^{-1}]\to R$ and invertible elements of $R$ . Where $R$ is commutative ring with 1.

Tags: abstract-algebra

As from this link
[Find a fixed commutative ring $R_0$ with 1, such that for every commutative ring $R$ with 1 $Hom(R_0)\to $ invertible elements of $R$ is bijection.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4302782/find-a-fixed-commutative-ring-r-0-with-1-such-that-for-every-commutative-ring?noredirect=1#comment8961787_4302782)

azif00 suggested a good ring $\mathbb Z[x,x^{-1}]$

I want for every invertible element in $r$ there is one and only one ring homomorphism $\mathbb Z[x,x^{-1}]\to R$.

If $r$ is invertible I can find a canonical homomorphism $\mathbb Z[x,x^{-1}]\to R$ which is evaluation at the point $r$. Which is well defined since r is invertible and it is a ring homomorphism.

Question: How we know that every morphism $\mathbb Z[x,x^{-1}]\to R$ is in the type of above evaluation morphism.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Your question amounts to this: For a ring homomorphism $f : \mathbb Z[x, x^{-1}] \to R$ you need an element $r$ such that $f$ is evaluation-at-$r$. To see how to find this, first find a way to get $r$ back from the evaluation-at-$r$ homomorphism. You should get something you can do to any homomorphism; show that the result will always be a unit.

You now have two maps, namely
$$
   \varphi : R^\times \to \operatorname{Hom}(\mathbb Z[x, x^{-1}], R)\\
   r \mapsto \text{evalution-at-$r$}
$$
and the map
$$
   \psi : \operatorname{Hom}(\mathbb Z[x,x^{-1}], R) \to R^\times
$$
you found above.

Show that these are mutual inverses, i.e. show that $\varphi \circ \psi$ and $\psi \circ \varphi$ are both the identity on their respective domain.

---

Some more details: To get an $r \in R^\times$ from $f : \mathbb Z[x,x^{-1}] \to R$, you can compute $f(x)$ where $x$ is the indeterminate of $\mathbb Z[x,x^{-1}]$. This will certainly be an element of $R$, you need to check that it will be a unit. (How might one find an inverse?)

This is how you get the map $\psi$ above. Now you need to check that the two compositions are the identity.

So if you start with an element of $R^\times$, you need to show that
$$
  \psi(\varphi(r)) = r,
$$
in other words, if you take the evaluate-at-$r$ map (which is written $\varphi(r)$ here) and apply it to the element $x \in \mathbb Z[x, x^{-1}]$ (i.e. calculate $\varphi(r)(x)$) you get $r$ back.

And if you start with a homomorphism $f : \mathbb Z[x,x^{-1}] \to R$, you need to show that
$$
  \varphi(\psi(f)) = f.
$$
In other words, you take the evaluate-at-$f(x)$ map and show that it is equal to $f$ (for example, by showing that $f(a) = \varphi(\psi(f))(a)$ for all $a \in \mathbb Z[x,x^{-1}]$).

Comment: I mean no disrespect but the whole point of my question is to find a way "to get r back from the evaluation-at-r homomorphism"

Comment: I’m sure you can find that yourself! (This is not a site that wants to do your homework for you.) If I give you a homomorphism $f : \mathbb Z[x,x^{-1}] \to R$ and you want an element of $R$ (let’s go for *any* element for now), there is really only one type of operation you can do to $f$ to achieve that. What is it?

Comment: Inverse but, ok assume any $r\in R$ then consider fiber of r $f^{-1}(r)\subseteq \mathbb Z[x,x^{-1}]$ then $f(f^{-1}(r))$ maps via f to $r$

Comment: You don’t need inverses here. If $f$ is as in my previous comment, what is $f(0)$? In particular, which ring does it belong to? And if $f$ is evaluation-at-$r$, can you do something similar to get $r$? (Remember that you do know what element of the domain look like.)

Comment: I tried everything again. I am really sorry and so dumb not to get it.

$f(0)$ means $0$ in $\mathbb Z[x,x^{-1}]$ maps to $0\in R$ since R is ring. $f(0)$ belongs to $R$ and $(0)$.

For the earlier: about what you said in answer since every element $\in Z[x,x^{-1}]$ maps to some $r\in R$ it is natural to think these laurent series are some what evaluation at some point but again why every homomorphism is evaluation homomorphism dont get it.

Comment: I am really in pain because can't understand :(

Comment: Well, if $f$ is the evaluate-at-$r$ map, can you calculate what $f(x)$ is (where $x$ is the indeterminate in $\mathbb Z[x, x^{-1}]$?

Comment: I amended my answer with some more details but I won’t check back again, today.